# Installing KVM Broke Current asp.net vnext Web Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I installed the KVM using command line and my web project in VS2015 preview broke not compiling, but if add a new web project all works fine, how do uninstall the KVM so I can get my old project working. In this video Scott mention the issue but no solution, please see link, the video mention the issue at the 8:00 minute
[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei0nm.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei0nm.png): http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Whats-New-with-ASPNET-5/05 I change the to use the default alias but that did not work

[image]

[image]

NuGet Settings

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your versions are out of sync.  Check your project.json and make sure you are not using different versions.  I found that when I had 1 dependency that used 3.0.0-* it upgraded to beta2 from beta1.  All of my other dependencies had beta1 actually defined. (Ex: 1.0.0-beta1). If the beta2 assembly shares the same dependency as one of your assemblies using beta1 it will override the older version of the shared assembly that is being used and causes your older version to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any KRE package by deleting it from `c:\Users\<user>\.kre\packages\`. If you want to remove KRE and KVM then remove both the `.kre` folder completely.

However, you don't have to remove it to use a different version. You can either use `kvm use <version>` or, from VS, select the target framework in the project properties.

Comment: I did that and changed the property on the project and still does not work.

Comment: Can you check in VS to see if all the NuGet sources are enabled? There is a bug that disables the official nugget source and some packages fail to restore. If that doesn't fix the problem, please show us the errors that you get

Comment: What do you mean by "All the NuGet sources are enabled", please let me know where in VS and I can enable that I'm using VS2015 Preview, I added image for the nuget settings

Comment: Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources

Comment: basically all the dependencies are not been added to the project that include System, System.String, System.Object and any Microsoft  dependencies including ASPNet.MVC

Comment: Can you post the contents of project.json?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and I solved it by following steps.

1. In NUget Package Manager I selected only one nuget.org ( Disable myget.org by unselecting it)
2. I goto C:\Users\<>.kre\alias  directory. Here you will find default.txt and I replace default.txt value with KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1 ( If you downloaded latest version of Kre then this file change and it create problem for VS 2015 Preview)
3. After this close your solution and open it again. If possible then open as Administrator.

I hope this works for you as well.