# Reference Issue/Missing Types

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm periodically getting the following error on Windows 7 in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5 with ASP.NET 5 projects:

- Code:  CS0518
- Description:  Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Other core types, like Int32 & String, show the same error.

I'm using the nightly builds on MyGet and beta2 of the KRE if that matters.  I have removed "aspnetcore50" from my list of frameworks, and only have "aspnet50" in my project.json.

This seems to happen for no rhyme or reason (ex. load the project in VS in the morning), and I typically have to scratch my project and recreate it to make progress.  Has anyone else faced this issue?  Is there anything that I can try to fix the problem?  I found that unloading/reloading the project in VS works sometimes, but it usually does not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure exactly what caused the issue, but I *think* that it was caused by running "kvm update" and/or using beta4 packages with a beta 2 KRE.  Anyways, here is what I did to resolve the issue:

- deleted all K runtimes at %userprofile%.kre\packages
- deleted all Nuget packages at %userprofile%.kpm\packages
- manually installed beta2 K runtimes
- changed package version in project.json to beta2 ("1.0.0-beta2" or "6.0.0-beta2")
- set the correct KRE in project settings
- unloaded/reloaded project file

The issue has not resurfaced for me so far.  If I find anything else out, I'll be sure to update this post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was caused by project dependencies ending up with 1.0.0-beta4 (because of 1.0.0-* in project.json) and I was using 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: Thanks!  I think that this is part of the problem, but not the only issue.  I'm up and running again now, and if that continues, I will post what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This likely happens when you add a reference to a Portable Class Library.  The project system for .csproj files will automatically add references to the Portable Facade Assemblies it detects that an added references is a PCL, but I don't believe the ASP.NET vNext project system does that.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that this is the issue, but I'm still new to ASP.NET 5 (like most).  All of my references are coming directly from the Asp.Net team's MyGet feed, and everything works fine for a period of time until...well until it suddenly doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953179/installing-kvm-broke-current-asp-net-vnext-web-project), maybe is not the same thing but on my case I had on my project.json Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-*, and when they release the beta2 version VS got the all the dependencies for SignalR witch were beta2 and this conflicted with others dependencies that were beta1.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue for me, though I did experience some conflicts in the beginning.  The error seems to happen without reason.  For example, I have seen the issue where I close VS to do something else (everything was okay upon closing), but when I opened the project later, everything was broken and nothing was changed.

Comment: Could it be K runtime issue?  I'm using beta2, but I noticed that my dependencies are beta4.

Comment: What did on my project was KVM install and did install the beta2. I did KVM upgrade and that cause a lot of problem before.

Comment: I did run KVM upgrade, and I believe that is part of the issue.  I removed all KRE versions manually and then installed each beta2 version that I needed explicitly.  So far so good, but I needed to do a few other things to build again.