# VS2015 CTP5 Does not resolve references but still builds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

VS2015 CTP5 We are encountering this weird situation where VS2015 will build the project but intellisense is non-functional (see screenshot).  It can't even resolve the reference to System.  We have duplicated this behavior on the generated project templates that ship with VS2015. There must be a switch somewhere in VS2015 that I have in the wrong position... Does anyone out there know what I am doing wrong to cause this?

[Link to screen shot](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/342)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that error also when upgrading.  After running kvm restore and making sure all the assemblies were compatible, it fixed the issue.  See the following links and hopefully it will help you:

[Installing KVM Broke Current asp.net vnext Web Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953179/installing-kvm-broke-current-asp-net-vnext-web-project/28029508#2802950)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that incompatibilities between KRE versions and NuGet packages can cause VS2015CTP5 to fails badly meaning it is impossible from error messages to discover the problem.  When I switched my KRE and the NuGet packages to beta-2 versions this completely resolved the issue.