# ASP vNext all references missing

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I opened my project up this morning and it said I was missing every single reference and I have no idea how to fix it.
 [image]

I think I fixed it before by deleting the project and copying the files into another project but I don't want to do that again.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add the output of the package restore? (Output window -> Package manager log)

Comment: If you ask for my humble opinion your question is really valid. I will edit your question to remove the asp.net tag since is not valid on this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I crossed referenced my project.json and the references list and the versions didn't match.

In my project.json I had defined it to use 1.0.0-beta2 but in the references it said I was using 1.0.0-beta3-{build}. So that is what caused it to not build.

The way I fixed it was I went to:

> %USERPROFILE%.kpm\

and deleted all the folders from there. I then closed the solution and reopened it and all was well the versions matched again and I could build my project.

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things (sad but is true). Usually when that happens is because you have a miss match on a dependency or you have the project on a KRE version that it's no compatible with the version of your dependencies. In my case I added a to my project a dependencies version a 1.0.0.*-, the * will get lattes of that dependency if for some reason your have other dependencies are not compatible with the lattes one will the VS2015 will go crazy and will not know what yo chose.

It will help to see all your project.json from your solution. Microsft team mention of some of their blog the issue will go away once they move from beta to RC

please see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953179/installing-kvm-broke-current-asp-net-vnext-web-project)

Comment: Thanks, helped me figure out what was happening in my case and posted how I fixed it below.